# How to submit details of your form to a database when using asp.net mvc?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework-6

I want to find a way, to submit details of a user details to a database. I have table name (empty columns) with stored procedure for adding fields once save to a database. I am using ASP.NET MVC, all of these details within a form are on controller, model. I will share my code on client side for understanding as to what exactly my application has to do on a back end with controller. I am not using Entity Framework, my datasource is configured in a `web.config` and using data migration to access the schema on my model(ApplicationDbContext).

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=GcobaniM-L\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=eNtsaRegistration;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

@using eNtsaRegistrationTraining.Models
@model RoleViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Ttile = "Dashboard";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_HomeLayout.cshtml";
}

<!---This form is for registration within a Dashbaord layout-->
<center>
    <div class="z-inex" style="width:1000px;">
        <div class="register-logo">

        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body register-card-body">
                <center>
                    <img src="~/Images/eNtsa.png" />
                </center>
                <center>
                    <h1>
                        <p><b>Training Course Registration:Motion MasterClass</b></p>
                    </h1>
                    <hr />
                    <p>Course date: 25-27 February 2020</p>
                    <hr />
                    <p>
                        Note:Please note your registration is submit approval as seats for this course is limited. Once your registration is confirmed, you will receive a quote for subject to your confirmation
                        followed by an invoice.
                    </p>
                </center>
                <hr />
                @using (Html.BeginForm("editRegForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @role = "form" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <!--All controls for send data to the database be created-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="Title">Title:</label>
                        <div class="input-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 ">
                            <div class="input-group pull-right">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HomeMainModel.Title, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "title", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "Title", required = "required" })
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <form>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">

                            </div>
                            <label for="firstName">Name:</label>
                            <div class="input-group col-md-7 col-md-offset-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
                                <div class="input-group pull-right">
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HomeMainModel.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "firstname", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "First Name", required = "required" }) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HomeMainModel.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "lastname", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "Last Name", required = "required" })
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <div class="input-group-text">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <hr />

                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="Position">Position</label>
                        <div class="input-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                            <div class="input-group pull-right">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HomeMainModel.Position, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "position", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "Position", required = "required" })
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="Address">Company</label>
                        <div class="input-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                            <div class="input-group pull-right">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HomeMainModel.Company, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "company", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "Company", required = "required" })
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr />
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="Address">Address</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 ">
                            <div class="input-group pull-right">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HomeMainModel.Address, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "inputFormVal", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "Street Address", required = "required" })
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label id="labelMessageBx" class="text-danger" style="display:none"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 ">
                            <div class="input-group pull-right">
                                &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HomeMainModel.Address, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "inputFormVal", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "Street Address Line 2", required = "required" })

                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label id="labelMessageBx" class="text-danger" style="display:none"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">

                            <div class="input-group-prepend">

                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group col-md-7 col-md-offset-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
                                <div class="input-group pull-right">
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HomeMainModel.City, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "inputFormVal", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "City" })&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HomeMainModel.Code, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "inputFormVal", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "Province" })

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label id="labelMessageBx" class="text-danger" style="display:none"></label>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <!--Zip code for postal code-->
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">

                            <div class="input-group-append">

                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group col-md-7 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                                <div class="input-group pull-right">
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HomeMainModel.Code, new
                               {
                                   @class = "form-control",
                                   type = "text",
                                   id = "inputFormVal",
                                   autofocus = "autofocus",
                                   placeholder = "Postal/Zip Code"

                                    })
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HomeMainModel.SelectedCountryId, this.ViewBag.CountryList as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })

                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <div class="input-group-text">

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label id="labelMessageBx" class="text-danger" style="display:none"></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                            <div class="input-group pull-right">
                                <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <input class="form-control" type="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email address" />
                                <div class="input-group-append">

                                    <div class="input-group-text">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label id="labelMessage" class="text-danger" style="display:none">This field is required</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                            <div class="input-group pull-right">
                                <label for="AlternativeCellNumber">Cell Number:</label>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="cellNumber" placeholder="Cell Number" />
                                <div class="input-group-append">

                                    <div class="input-group-text">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                            <label id="labelMessagec" class="text-danger" style="display:none">This field is required</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr />
                    <form>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label for="Please verify that you are a human">Please verify that you are a human</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                            <div class="input-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-2">
                                <div class="input-group pull-left">
                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("FormSubmit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                                    {
                                        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LezHOIUAAAAANq0FvFWWbvBlb6Vc1Y2YwnixVqJ">

                                        </div>



                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <hr />

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                <label for="Dietary_Req">Dietary Requirement</label>
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group col-md-offset-3 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
                                    <div class="input-group pull-right">
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DietaryModel.None)
                                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DietaryModel.None)

                                    </div>
                                    <hr />
                                    <div class="input-group col-md-offset-3 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
                                        <div class="input-group pull-right">
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DietaryModel.Vegetarian)
                                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DietaryModel.Vegetarian)
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr />
                                    <div class="input-group col-md-offset-3 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
                                        <div class="input-group pull-right">
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DietaryModel.Vegan)
                                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DietaryModel.Vegan)
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr />
                                    <div class="input-group col-md-offset-3 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
                                        <div class="input-group pull-right">
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DietaryModel.Halaal)
                                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DietaryModel.Halaal)
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr />
                                    <div class="input-group col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                        <div class="input-group pull-right">
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DietaryModel.Other)
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DietaryModel.Other, new
                                            {
                                                @class = "form-control",
                                            type = "text",
                                            autofocus = "autofocus",
                                            placeholder = "Other"
                                            })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <hr />

                    <!--Submit form button to allow insert data to db-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <hr />
                        <button type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        @ViewBag.Message
                    </div>

                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




</center>

<!----Javascript for form validation including recapture on Google-->

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>


<!---Handling of error handling for the form-->

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
        //When the blur event occurs from your Textbox (you lose focus)
        $('#inputEmail').blur(function () {
            var email = document.getElementById("inputEmail").value;
            var expr = /^([\w-\.]+)@@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
            if (!expr.test(email)) {
                document.getElementById("labelMessage").style.display = "inline";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("labelMessage").style.display = "none";
            }
        });

    });

    // function when leaving texbox for cell number.
    $(function () {
        $('#cellNumber').blur(function () {
            var cell = document.getElementById("cellNumber").value;
            var expr = /^([\w-\.]+)@@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
            if (!expr.test(cell)) {
                document.getElementById("labelMessagec").style.display = "inline";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("labelMessagec").style.display = "none";
            }
        });
    });

    // function when leaving a caption.
    $(function () {
        $('#capTion').blur(function () {
            var captionz = document.getElementById("#capTion").value;
            if (!expr.test(captionz)) {
                document.getElementById("labelMessageG").style.display = "inline";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("labelMessageG").style.display = "none";
            }

        });

    });

    // function when leaving texbox for city, street address, street_address_line2, state_province.

    $(function () {
        $('#inputFormVal').blur(function () {
            var city = document.getElementById("inputFormVal").value;
            var expr = /^([\w-\.]+)@@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
            if (!expr.test(city)) {
                document.getElementById("labelMessageBx").style.display = "inline";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("labelMessageBx").style.display = "none";
            }
        });
    });




</script>
```

Comment: Please show this "data source in web.config", it's not quite clear what you mean. Are you talking about the connection string? And what is "ApplicationDbContext" if it isn't an Entity Framework object? You've said you aren't using entity framework, but you've tagged the question with it, and also mentioned an object name which sounds very like an entity framework thing. It might help to show us the web config and also your current model and controller code. Most of this client-side code is irrelevant to your issue.

Comment: Anyway you can find lots of Entity Framework (or ADO.NET, if you prefer not to use Entity Framework) tutorials online, to help you get started. We're not really a tutorial site. We'll help you once you've studied the basics and then made some kind of attempt. If you really have no idea where to start, that's the time for tutorials or courses or books. We can't teach you all the key concepts in a single answer here.

Comment: @ADyson i have included connection string from web.config. I have plenty of times studies ADO.Net and some videos as well.

Comment: Ok, so if you've done those studies, then what exactly is the difficulty you're experiencing? It's a bit unclear what is preventing you from starting to write the relevant code. What thing(s) don't you understand? Did you also study Microsoft's ASP.NET MVC tutorial - it shows you how to link the view, model and data storage all together.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson for raising something important, i was missing a scope within. Let me work on something i saw on the Microsoft Documentation, then i will re-post a challenge